# Not working jquery Post request

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm writing page on django. Not working jquery Post request. Nothing happens after click on #encrypt. I'm tried make request by $.get, $.ajax - nothing. everything works before `$.post`

home.html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#encrypt").click(function () {
        var postData = {
            text: $("#input-box").val(),
            rotate: $("#rotate").val()
        };
        $.post('encrypt', postData, function (data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response("home.html", {})

def encrypt(request):
    text=request.POST["text"]
    #some manipulation with text
    return render_to_response("home.html", {'text': text})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', caesar.views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^encrypt$', caesar.views.encrypt, name="encrypt")
]
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with some things that you've already tried? If you add a breakpoint to the event handler, do you see it get hit / how far does it get?

Comment: Looks like there is a syntax error. "function data {" should be: "function (data) {".

Comment: just mistake in text. In my code it is not

Comment: Hmm, looks like you got the URL wrong. Try changing $.post('encrypt', to $.post('/encrypt',

Comment: Now is likely work, but alert(data); show html code of this page.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `$.post()` is outside the click function handler. Remove the extra `});` just before it.

Proper indentation would probably have allowed you to spot that yourself.